# code explanation c++ [struct / two diamentinal array / pointers]

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm new to c++ and its developing.i have two methods void accumulation(void) & void chartest( char * nam) accumulation is called in my main.cpp file.

```
void accumulation(void)
{
  char * test[] ={"Rehan ","Kalpana"};
  chartest(&test[0][1]);
}

void chartest( char * nam)
{
    printf("char name -> %s \n",nam);
}
```

i changed the values in chartist as follows then i got output as follows

```
chartist(&test[0][1] - char name -> ehan
chartest(&test[1][1])-char name -> alpana
chartest(&test[1][0]) -char name -> Kalpana
chartest(&test[0][0])- char name -> Rehan
```

can anyone please explain why this happens. it will help me a lot. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You're basically just accessing a certain character in your string and casting it to a char array (retrieving it's address).

```
test[0][0] = "Rehan" = 'R'   // type: char
              ^
test[0][1] = "Rehan" = 'e'   // type: char
               ^

&test[0][0] = "Rehan"        // type: char*
&test[0][1] = "ehan"         // type: char*
```

You're just offsetting the beginning of the string.

Hope I'm making sense.

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
chartest(&test[0][1]);
```

You are passing the address of the character at `test[0][1]`, i.e.

```
Memory : 900 901 902 903 904 905 906 907
          R   E   H   A   N       \0
              ^ <-This address is being sent to the chartest() function.
```

Now the `chartest()` prints the resulting `char *` passed.

As `printf()` with `%s` prints the string until the `\0` is encountered,
in the first case, the `chartest()` will print `EHAN`.